# Filtering out surplus GPS track points

Tags: geolocation, gps, tracking

Im writing an app that functions much like RunKeeper. Im tracking CLLocations every x seconds to figure out the total distance.

However, if the user moves on a really straight freeway for 10 minutes (Think USA), there is no point in saving 60 tracking points.

What kind of filtering do you use in your apps to reduce the number of track points?

Im thinking about checking the course delta from the last good position and discarding the new posotion if course hasnt changed by more than x degrees. There would of course also be a longer time limit to get a point every now and then anyway.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the number of track points?

Comment: @AlexWien Because i might send them to a server or show them on a map. If i send them somewhere i want to reduce the size and server load, if i draw them on a map the less points the better the performance.